# Official badge for GitHub actions

Tags: github, badge, github-actions

Does GitHub have an official 'badge' for their new 'actions' feature?

I came across [this request](https://github.com/badges/shields/issues/2574) on their official repo and there seems to be an official one:

```
https://github.com/{github_id}/{repository}/workflows/{workflow_name}/badge.svg
```

as per [this comment](https://github.com/badges/shields/issues/2574#issuecomment-522575868), but I am unable to get it to work.  Is it actually working?  When I use it, I get the below output:

[image: Unrendered GitHub badge]

Note that I have replaced `{github_id}` with my `username`, `{repository}` with my repo name and `{workflow_name}` with the corresponding workflow name (removing the curly braces).  Does anyone else have this issue?
Edit: I am working on a private repo, in case it makes a difference.

Comment: I suspect that since your repo is private, you would need to provide some sort of authentication in the URL to make it work, which isn't great as that would expose your repo's access token to anyone who looked at the HTML. Maybe make a test repo (that's public) and see if that makes a difference. If the badge for the public repo works, then you know the problem is authentication.

Comment: @rmunn, thank you for your reply.  Turns out, the badge 'update' is a very slow process.  I just created another branch and started doing rest of the stuff.  After about 10-15 minutes, I noticed that the image had updated, but the pipeline status was 'unknown'.  After some more time (I think around 10 minutes), the badge became green as required.  Unlike azure-pipelines, etc. which are quick, this renders pretty slowly for some reason.

Comment: Great; glad that it's working. Since it's working, I'd suggest that you answer your own question, then after 48 hours have passed you can accept your own answer. That will let people know, if they later find your question in a search, that the question isn't still waiting for an answer.

Comment: @rmunn, fair enough.  Sorry that it took me so long, but I have noted my observations below.  I agree it is a good idea.

Comment: You can simply copy the correct markdown from your own repository Actions tab > Select the workflow > Click on the Create status badge button. This worked for my private and internal repos.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As it turns out, badge update/rendering is a slow process.  After adding the badge to my `README.md`, I just started off with work in another branch.  After about 10 minutes (at least in my case), the badge appeared but the pipeline status was shown as 'unknown'.  It updated again after about 10 minutes and with the correct pipeline status ('passing' in my case).

So, once you are done, just continue with your other stuff and it will update on its own, in sometime.  Hope this helps someone!

Comment: yes, this should be improved.

Answer (score 63):

You can get the actions badge by navigating to the required workflow on your repo on GitHub.com, clicking on the settings button on the right (the one with 3 dots beside the workflow search) and clicking on the **Create status badge** button.

[image]

Here, you can select the badge for the required **branch** and **event** and use the generated markdown.

For eg, below is the badge that I generated for the default branch and event of the `CI` workflow of my fork:

[image: Build and Deploy]

The markdown for the above badge:

```
[![Build and Deploy](https://github.com/kratostaine/spring-authorization-server/actions/workflows/continuous-integration-workflow.yml/badge.svg)](https://github.com/kratostaine/spring-authorization-server/actions/workflows/continuous-integration-workflow.yml)
```

Comment: No I can't. My workflow is triggered by workflow_dispatch and the badge always says "failed build" even though the build succeeds.

Comment: FWIW, as I write this, there no longer is a "Create status badge" button after selecting the workflow under Actions. OK, I've got to amend what I said. Clicking the button with the 3 dots immediately to the right of the "Filter workflow runs" textbox, produces a dropdown with "Create status badge" and "Disable workflow" as options.

Comment: Thank you for highlighting, @Rod. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

Worked for me:

```
[GITHUB-BADGE](https://github.com/{username}/{repository}/workflows/{name}/badge.svg)
```

[image: GITHUB-BADGE]

More info here: [Adding a workflow status badge to your repository](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/adding-a-workflow-status-badge)

Comment: Link is dead, currently can be found at https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/managing-workflow-runs/adding-a-workflow-status-badge

Answer (score 6):

I ran into another related problem of the name of the workflow containing spaces. These have to use URI escapes:

From main.yml

```
name: Hello World
```

Has to use a URI formatted like this:

```
https://github.com/{username}/{repository}/workflows/Hello%20World/badge.svg
```

This is not the right answer to the exact problem described here, but it is an alternative remedy to a problem demonstrating the same diagnostics - so I hope it helps somebody.